# adobe flex static function reference control

Tags: apache-flex, static, adobe, public, viewstack

Is it possible to reference a control in an application from a static function?

What I have is a Viewstack containing VBoxes stored in separate controls. Ex:

```
<mx:ViewStack id="content" width="100%" height="100%" resizeToContent="true">
    <controls:Login/>
    <controls:Dash/>            
    <controls:Input/>   
    <controls:Review/>
    <controls:Search/>  
</mx:ViewStack>
```

Once I get logged in on my login control, I would like to change the selected index of my ViewStack.  From my outside controls, I cannot reference my ViewStack by name.  I can reference a public static function from an outside control however I cannot refer to the ViewStack from within that function.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

JH

Comment: Why can't you reference your ViewStack by name? Where are you in relation to your ViewStack?

Comment: Can you post the code of the static function that you tested with and that doesn't work so that we understand your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Normally you can have a singleton class where you can save the
>   instance of the main application and if you view stack is resides
>   inside your main application then you can do some thing like this

```
public static function changeIndex(index:int):void
{
    FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.content.selectedIndex = index;
    //urappinstance.content.selectedIndex = index;
}
```

Comment: FlexGlobals worked perfectly for me.  I was able to place this code in my public class and reference it from all of my controls.  Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You could reach it starting from FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication (if it is visible from there). Although, the design of such a thing may be questionable.

Comment: Eduardo/rajesh.adhi, I would vote both of your responses up, but I don't have enough cred. :-P.  Thanks anyway for your help.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to reference a control in an application from a static
>   function?

Generally no.  A static function (or property) exists on the class itself.  Whereas MXML Children--such as in a view stack--exist on a specific instance of the class.  A class level function will know nothing about any specific instances of the class and will not be able to access properties on a specific instance.

However, you can pass an instance of a class into a static function and access the properties that way.  something like this:

```
public static function doStuff(myViewStack:ViewStack):void{
 trace(myViewStack.id)
 // do other stuff
}
```

And call it like this:

```
MyClass.doStuff(content)
```